# Azure WebFunction does not respect host.json file

Tags: azure, .net, azure-web-apps

I'm running a **WebFunction** of type **ServiceBusTrigger**.

Depending on the case, I need to abandon the message and put it back in the queue. However, I can only run it again after 30 seconds. I have already configured **host.json** according to MS [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus?tabs=in-process%2Cextensionv5%2Cextensionv3&pivots=programming-language-csharp), but it has no effect.

Follow the code

**host.json**

```
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensions": {
    "serviceBus": {
      "clientRetryOptions": {
        "mode": "exponential",
        "maxRetries": 2,
        "delay": "00:00:30.00",
        "tryTimeout": "00:01:00",
        "maxDelay": "00:01:00"
      },
      "maxMessageBatchSize": 2
    }
  }
}
```

**function**

```
using Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace Teste;

public class FTeste
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public FTeste(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<FTeste>();
    }

    [Function("F_Testes")]
    public async Task RunAsync([ServiceBusTrigger("q_teste", Connection = "ServiceBusConnection", IsBatched = true)]
        ServiceBusReceivedMessage[] messages,
        ServiceBusMessageActions messageActions)
    {
        foreach (var message in messages)
        {
            try
            {
                _logger.LogInformation($"Executou: {message.Body} às {DateTime.Now}");

                if (message.Body.ToString().Contains("erro"))
                {
                    await messageActions.AbandonMessageAsync(message);
                    _logger.LogInformation($"{message.Body} voltou para a fila às {DateTime.Now}");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError(ex, ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I execute it, the message it abandons (with an error) returns to the queue, but it is executed again immediately afterwards, not respecting the file configuration (**delay**) of 30 seconds.

Similarly to retries (**maxRetries**), it executes as configured in the Azure panel (5) and not according to **host.json**

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that clientRetryOptions would apply to the function instance interaction with the service bus and is used for transient fault handling, which is independent of the function instancing through the trigger scale controller.

Therefore logically your scenario would only work if the function was setup as a singleton, otherwise when you abandon the message another instance of the function would be able to pick up the message immediately (as the lock would have been released) up to the max [re-delivery]attempts allowed. There's a few community articles available to help you with setting up a function as a singleton.

I guess as an alternative to using a singleton function you could also consider a thread wait/delay of 30seconds in the error condition before you "abandon" the message and that would work OK so long as you have that much time remaining on the lock - this feels a bit "hacky" though.